# Firebird-SQL: showing predefined values instead of nothing

Tags: sql, firebird

i need to write an SQL query which is similar to the following:

```
SELECT c.*, p.amount
FROM claims c, payments p
WHERE claims.debit < payments.amount AND c.customerId = p.customerId
```

Now the problem is, that this query only shows claims, which have a payment which belongs to this claims. But I want it to show every claim and if there's no belonging payment the amount should just be zero.

How can i achieve this?

Btw, I'm doing this in Firebird-SQL.

And sorry for the bad title, i have no idea how to describe it better.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do a LEFT JOIN, but also putting the "<" construction in the JOIN condition.

```
select c.*,
       coalesce(p.amount, 0) amount
  from claims c
  left outer join payments p
    on c.customerId = p.customerId and
       c.debit < p.amount
```

If you do like @whirl-mind said, the WHERE will be evaluated against "NULL values" and it will filter out the records.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Left Outer Join`.

```
SELECT c.*, p.amount
FROM claims c Left Outer Join  payments p On c.customerId = p.customerId
WHERE claims.debit < payments.amount
```

Not sure about Firebird-SQL,you should be able to use an IsNull phrase or a Case Statement to fetch 0 if the payment is null.